# R graphics/ggplot2 to reproduce faceting with highlighted "active" line and the other lines greyed out

Tags: r, ggplot2, graphics

Is there a way to accomplish this type of faceting in ggplot2 or any other plotting library available in R?

Here is an attempt to create some dummy data.

```
library(tidyverse)

country <- c(rep("Bahrain", 30), rep("Chile", 30), rep("Czech Rep.", 30))
day <- rep(1:30, 3)
cases <- c(runif(n = 30, 1, 5), runif(n = 30, 5, 10), runif(n = 30, 1, 20)) %>% round()

# trying to create some dummy data
df <- tibble(country, day, cases) %>%
  group_by(country) %>%
  mutate(cases = cumsum(cases))

# creating a plot with basic faceting
ggplot(df, aes(day, cases)) +
  geom_line() +
  facet_wrap(~country)
```

[image: Only a subset of countries is shown.]

Comment: To answer your question, yes it is possible to do that graph in `r`. However, I can't show you how to do it solely based on what you are providing. Your link is available only if you paid for Financial Times. Please read this link to know how to provide a good reproducible example on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-exampledata

Comment: I removed the link to the FT article. I hope you might deduce from the picture in the question what I am trying to accomplish.

Comment: I can deduce what functions you will have to use but I can't write the code that will make the figure without a reproducible data example.

Comment: I have added some dummy data I created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, I think the use of `gghighlight` could be helpful:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(gghighlight)
ggplot(df, aes(cases, day, color = country)) +
  geom_line() +
  gghighlight()+
  facet_wrap(~country)
```

[image]

Does it answer your question ?

Official documentation for `gghighlight`: https://yutannihilation.github.io/gghighlight/articles/gghighlight.html

Comment: Great answer! Thanks a lot.